# How to maximize a simple expression in Python

Tags: python, math

How do you write a Python program that solves the following problem:

> Find two non-negative integers whose sum is 12 and that maximize the product of the first number and 3 raised to the power of the second number.

Comment: Should it be xy^3? Since you mentioned the power of 3.

Comment: @m170897017 yes off course , typing error. I'll edit my question

Comment: can we assume those are integers? if so, you only have 13 different choices. can you write a loop for that? do you know how to find a maximum?

Comment: If `x` and `y` aren't constrained to be integers, then the only way to solve this numerically is with a root finding algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes those two are non-negative numbers.

Comment: @n.imp A "non-negative number" is not necessarily an integer!

Comment: @WillVousden yes , So any example from where I can get an idea how to solve these kind of problems

Comment: one way - if you know that the numbers are integers is to write a brute force algorithm - i.e. a set of loops which check all possible values.

Comment: You have to find the algorythme of resolution of the problem - Python will not be of great help in that part - and then you code it it Python. If you do not need how Python read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). As currently written the question too broad.

Comment: @n.imp - what makes you think that python is suitable for these types of problems ?

Comment: Solving this analytically is probably easier than doing it in Python...but if you want, check out Scipy, specifically the [optimize subpackage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Comment: so are they integers or not?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ok let us suppose they are integers

Comment: in that case you have to answer my questions.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry which question ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: You will probably want a loop from 0 to 12 to try the values for `x`. From that you should be able to compute `y`, and given `x` and `y`, you should be able to calculate `x` times `y` cubed. Start by assuming `x` = 0 is the best answer by saving that initial value of 0 in `best_so_far` and the value of `x` plus `y` cubed in `highest_value`. Then looping from 1 to 12, compare the value of `x` times `y` cubed to `highest_value`; if the new value is greater, save it in `highest_value` and save `x` in `best_so_far`. If it's not, move on to the next value.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon I am little bit confused by your comment can you write in mathematical form or code and post it as answer so that if it works I can accept that

Comment: At this point it's up to you to show us some attempt at code. That's the basic algorithm; try something and see if it works.

Comment: As we cannot enter any more answers...
`a = { x : x * (12-x)**3 for x in range(0,12) }
xmax = max(a, key=a.get)
print(xmax, 12-xmax)`
assuming we are after integers.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon I have submit my code as an answer (assuming for integers). I don't know is that fine or not , can you have a look at that and let me know tour thoughts .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this , I don't know its the best way but here is my code :

```
max = 0
first_no = None
second_no = None

for x in xrange(0,12):
    y = 12 - x
    P = x * pow(y, 3)
    if P > max:
        first_no = x
        first_no = y
        max = P
print "first no is %s" %(first_no)
print "Second no is %s" %(second_no)
print "Maximum number %s" %(max)
```

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable solution, and will answer the question for integers. You've got the basic idea; it's simply thinking out the process and then writing it down so that the computer can do the work.

Comment: You have one variable named first_no and another named f_no. That does not seem quite right. And first_no is a better name than f_no.

Comment: You should have tested the code before you posted it. All experienced SO members do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve equations in Built-in Functions of Python, but you can transform the problem so that the computer can attack that problem. For this particular example, there are several methods out there but using loops is probably the easiest to understand:

```
def getNumbers(sum,power):
    numberlist = [0,0]
    biggest = 0
    for i in range (1,sum):
        for j in range (1,sum):
            if (i+j == sum) and (i*(j**power) > biggest):
                numberlist = [i,j]
                biggest = i*(j**power)
    return numberlist,biggest

list, max = getNumbers(12,3)
print list, max
```

Now, if you need the decimal places, it gets tricky because of the rounding problems of Python. To overcome this, I'll need lots of `round()`. And don't be disappointed that the answers are actually whole numbers.

```
def getNumbers(sumNumber,powerNumber,decimalPlaces = 2):
    numberlist = [0.0,0.0]
    biggest = 0
    increment = 1.0
    for k in range (0, decimalPlaces):
        increment /= 10
    i = 1.0
    while i < sumNumber:
        j = 1.0
        while j < sumNumber:
            if round(i + j, decimalPlaces) ==  sumNumber and round(i*(j**powerNumber),decimalPlaces*3) > biggest:
                numberlist = [round(i,decimalPlaces),round(j,decimalPlaces)]
                biggest = round(i*(j**powerNumber),decimalPlaces*powerNumber+1)
            j += increment
        i += increment
    return numberlist,biggest

list, max = getNumbers(12,3,2)
print list, max
```

Comment: Just for future reference, why did I get a downvote?

Comment: I don't know, but I assume whoever did had two qualms: the first is that this doesn't directly answer the question (although it solves the example), the second is that the code isn't ideal.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep those things in mind when I post from now on.

Comment: @Tetsudou I ahve shared my code too , I don't know is that fine or not , can you have a look at that and let me know tour thoughts .

Comment: Your code looks fine. When I ran it, it gave me the right answers which were 3 and 9. I think you are confusing the variable names, because you never use first_no or second_no and instead you use f_no and s_no.

Comment: @Tetsudou Oh yes my mistake for variable names , I'll edit my answer